# Get data sorted even if some references are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null, sql-order-by

I want to order my results after a name. Thereby multiple tables are necessary. Now I have the problem that I want to sort the name even if there is a `null` in the column. Below you find a sample database which should represent the problem:

**My tables**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `manufacturer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

**My data:**

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `desc`, `price`, `manufacturer_id`) VALUES
(1, 'book', 12, 1),
(2, 'cup', 4, 2),
(3, 'Arbitrary product', 100, NULL);

INSERT INTO `manufacturer` (`id`, `title`, `desc`, `website`) VALUES
(1, 'Publisher', 'Lorem ipsum', 'www.stackoverflow.com'),
(2, 'Cup producer', 'Lorem ipsum', 'www.cup.com');
```

If I do a `SELECT * FROM products` than I would get three results. If I want to order it I have a query like

```
SELECT p.desc, p.price, m.title
FROM products p, manufacturer m
WHERE p.manufacturer_id = m.id
ORDER BY m.title
```

This gives me only two results because of the `null` value in `products`. Is it possible to sort the table `products` after the manufacturer title even there is a `null` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a join by saying p.manufacturer_id = m.id
But you didn't specify it so by default it's an inner join,
You want to have a left join where your 'left' table is the products table

```
SELECT p.desc, p.price, m.title
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN manufacturer AS m ON m.id = p.manufacturer_id
ORDER BY m.title
```

Have a look at this image for a better understanding
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_V2.png

Answer (score 1):

Use [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Try this:

```
SELECT p.desc, p.price, m.title
FROM products p LEFT OUTER JOIN manufacturer m
ON p.manufacturer_id = m.id
ORDER BY m.title
```